# Why does declaring an unsigned char "Volatile" make it incompatible with a "non-volatile" unsigned char?

Tags: c, pointers, volatile

I am trying to use a volatile unsigned char as a pointer array argument to a function. I created the function:

```
static void queue_to_serial(unsigned char *queue)
```

I'm using "static" for the function, because it is only to be used in the current source file. Then I call the function and supply the address:

```
queue_to_serial(&queue);
```

And I get an error:

```
Error[Pe167]: argument of type "unsigned char volatile (*)[8]" is incompatible with parameter of 
type "unsigned char *"
```

The array is declared as a volatile but from what I know that means it shall not be optimized out as it can change asynchronously

```
static volatile unsigned char queue[MAX_NUM_CONNECTED_VALVES];
```

The array is also declared to be static because I would like to retain the value assigned to the variable. Unless the array is updating at the exact time the function is run which should not happen this should in my mind work because the memory used by a volatile unsigned char is the same as an unsigned char. How does making a variable volatile change it? Or does declaring it as a pointer cause it to occupy memory at a different location? Thank you

Comment: You just need to do `queue_to_serial(queue);` `queue` is already a pointer. The volatile flag is unrelated to that error.

Comment: I actually tried that and the error persisted  *a and a[] are equivalent from what I know. Thanks!

Comment: `*a` and `a[]` are "equivalent" (not really but it depends on context), but you're passing `&queue` when `queue` is already an array of `char`. The error message shows this. Since you get a similar error message when you pass `queue`, you should update your question with that code and error message, which is closer to correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a function such as

```
int foo(char* x);
```

the compiler will generate some code for this function, which *does not* know anything about what kind of parameters you are going to *cast* to `char*` and pass to it. So it will assume `x` is a pointer to some regular memory that can be be optimized in usual way, and for example something like:

```
int foo(char* x) 
{
    a = x[0];
    b = x[0];
    return a + b;
}
```

could be optimized to something like `return 2 * x[0];` - that is performing a single read from `x[0]`.

Now consider

```
int bar(volatile char* x) 
{
    a = x[0];
    b = x[0];
    return a + b;
}
```

This time the compiler *must* generate two reads from `x`.

Why does it matter? Think that `x` is pointing to some hardware counter register, which will increment each time it is being read. So assuming it's initial value is `0`, the `foo(x)` call will return `0` and the value of the counter will be `1`. `bar(x)` will return `1` and the value of the counter will be `2`.

Comment: Are there any cases where there is some sort of "hardware counter register" like this?

Comment: @JL2210 Of course... When there is such a counter :) Or if you want a more real-life example - a register to read some serial port FIFO - each read it will automatically "pop" a byte from the FIFO.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is there any way I can emulate this (say every time I write a `short` to a location the pointer increments by `sizeof(short)`)?

Comment: @JL2210 If you have a debugger with some kind of watchpoint capabilities - you can set a write watchpoint on the location and it will break there - co you can either increment it manually or have it scripted (again, depends on the debugger)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is it possible to have a counter like this in a just out of real-mode 32-bit x86 environment?

Comment: @JL2210 It is really up to the specific hardware (and which is usually not accessible from user mode if speaking of operating systems, but can be definitely accessible by drivers in kernel modes). There is a common scheme of Index/data register pairs for some peripherals for example (where you write some "index" to on of the registers and can read the corresponding data from the other), which might implement auto-increment on the index, so one can continuously populate all the indices. By itself this feature won't be very useful I guess

Comment: I'll ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` was standardized in 1989 ANSI C at the same time as `const`, and was lumped into the same category as a type qualifier, following the same rules.

If you have a

```
void function(char *ptr);
```

then for obvious reasons, there is a diagnostic if you pass in the address of a `const char` object:

```
{ const char c = 'A'; function(&c); } /* diagnostic required */
```

How that works, formally, is that a pointer to a more qualified type cannot be implicitly converted into a pointer to a less qualified type.

Since `volatile` is in the same lexical category as `const` (it's a qualifier), it gets treated the same way.

Furthermore, if an object defined `volatile` is accessed through an lvalue that doesn't carry the `volatile` qualifier, the behavior is undefined. (Note that this is a looser requirement area than `const`: `const` objects are accessible through a non-const-lvalue; only modification is undefined.) I think this was added to the language to justify the treatment of the volatile concept as a qualifier similar to `const`; it doesn't actually make a whole lot of sense. It's just "the way it is".